# How to run long Web-Scraping scripts using Azure serverless architecture?

Tags: azure, web-scraping, azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine

I need to run a long web-scraping script (takes about an hour to complete) but the issue is Azure Functions times out after some time. Is it better to run the script on a VM instead? To keep Azure Function running, I'd either need a Premium App Service plan or modularize the code into separate functions. Not sure which would be more efficient, cost-wise and future maintenance wise.

Comment: Premium Functions (not Premium App Service plan) or Azure Container Instances come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically I feel you have a few options here:

1. You can use a function app on an elastic premium plan or dedicated plan and set the timeout to unlimited. Note it is guaranteed up to 60 minutes but can go longer but is at the mercy of possibility of stopping as mentioned in the note below->
   [image]
   {
   "functionTimeout": "-1"
   }

- Premium plan execution is only guaranteed for 60 minutes, but technically unbounded.
- A value of -1 indicates unbounded execution, but keeping a fixed upper bound is recommended.

2. You can use durable functions, Durable Functions provides built-in support for this pattern, simplifying or even removing the code you need to write to interact with long-running function executions. For example, the Durable Functions quickstart samples (C#, JavaScript, TypeScript, Python, PowerShell, and Java) show a simple REST command that you can use to start new orchestrator function instances. After an instance starts, the extension exposes webhook HTTP APIs that query the orchestrator function status.

   Just search for long running durable in any search engine and you can find the doc elaborating on this.(My recommended)
3. You can use a webjob of course as well which is normally what is used for long running executions along durable.
4. Use a normal web app for scraping, just ensure you have always on enabled!!
5. You can go to a vm as well, but that is outside my area. I think all have pros and cons, realistically durable or webjobs make the most sense in terms of cost and setup.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try these out and see what works best.